# I am new to Joomla and I'm trying to figure out if I need to install the software or if I can just log in online to make changes

Tags: module, user, database, update, installation

I recently started a summer job and it requires some website management. The company that hired me already has their website through Joomla! and I am just trying to figure out if I need to download Joomla or if I can just make changes online by logging into the back end of the website.

The company that hired me is in need of some website updates and provided me with the login info to the back end of things, but I have no idea where to start.

I have no knowledge on Joomla! so I started my research and I keep seeing things about a database and host options, but this has already been taken care of by the company. So I'm not sure how to go about the next steps. Anything will help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Hailey, we feel you.  We've all been at this point in our career at some point.  As a matter of keeping this Q&A site clean, full of good searchable content, and attractive to volunteer contributors/supporters, please ask narrow questions about what you need help with.  When your requirements are vague or broad, your question may be vulnerable to being closed.  Vague/Broad questions are typically less attractive to prospective answerers because they either don't know how much detail to go into, or they don't want to write a 5000 word tutorial.  If you can narrow your question please [edit].

Answer (score 0):

If you're just editing content, the most likely place it will be is in an article. You should be able to log into their site by adding /administrator to the end of the site URL (For example, https://thedomainname.com/administrator). Then use the login info they provided.

Once logged in, articles can be found under the "Content" main menu item.

Comment: If/When you are unsure about what kind of support an asker is seeking, it is often best to ask for clarification as a comment under the question.  Of course, you haven't unlocked this privilege yet, so the typical advise that we give is for you to begin your journey as a contributor by answering only clear, complete, on-topic questions.  After you answer a few of those, you will likely earn some rep.  Then you'll be able to help the asker to shape a good question without needing to guess what they actually need.  Food for thought.